# Array is null when trying to use .push after localstorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, null, push

I get a TypeError saying my array is null when I try to push a new value into it.

```
//first off..
var sillyArray= ["dummy"];
localStorage.setItem("sillyArray", JSON.stringify(sillyArray));

//I later used this
sillyArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sillyArray"));
//the error is here
sillyArray.push("yes");
localStorage.setItem("sillyArray", JSON.stringify(sillyArray));
```

Am I unable to push or parse this?

(Edited a posting error)

Comment: Are you sure your code is executing in the order that you think it is? (Maybe you have some asynchronous things going on?) If you called `.getItem()` *before* calling `.setItem()` then it would return `null`.

Comment: Would that be the only possibility? I have the localStorage.setItem("sillyArray", JSON.stringify(sillyArray));

in a if statement which I'm almost positive is executing I will look further into it nonetheless.

Comment: Nevermind, that's absolutely it. Thank you, now to painstakingly figure out what's wrong with it. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The `yesArray` was never `definded`. That's why it's impossible to `.push()`.

Comment: If it was never declared it can't be `null`, it will be `undefined`. But will give a reference error if you try to call `.push()` on it.

Comment: Yep. messed up on my post, the 'yesArray' is replaced with sillyArray in my code. Problem is still obviously present.

editing post to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but you are trying to push an item into a `undefined` var, this is why you get a **TypeError**.

Here is how you should do that:

```
var array = ['dummy'];
localStorage.setItem('someKey', JSON.stringify(array));
array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('someKey'));
array.push('foo');
localStorage.setItem('someKey', JSON.stringify(array));
```

then if you do

```
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('someKey')))
```

the output will be what you are expecting `["dummy", "foo"]`

Comment: It would be nice to explain what was wrong with the OP's code rather than leaving us to compare line by line (and variable name by variable name).

Comment: My bad, this still isn't the issue, I had just changed the array's names so it was easier to identify (Stupid right?), in this situation the yesArray.push would actually be sillyArray.push

Comment: @Sausejii the code that I've posted works. If you wanna try, copy-paste it to your browser's console.

Comment: Yeah! Yours works perfectly, I just thought I'd elaborate what the problem actually was(not explained in the question accidentally) so I used an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As user nnnnnn said, I hadn't properly executed my`localStorage.setItem("sillyArray", JSON.stringify(sillyArray));`

It was sitting in an if statement (*not pictured*) that wasn't executing causing the null.

Thanks guys!